# Append results to existing data in CSV using JENKINS powershell

Tags: powershell, shell, jenkins

I have the following expression in a function

```
Select-Object TimeCreated,@{Name='User Name';Expression={$_.Properties[0].Value}},@{Name='Source Host';Expression={$_.Properties[1].Value}}
```

which is producing an output when stored in $result and displayed as below

[image]

I want to append this $result data to an existing data in a CSV. I am using the following code but its not working

```
Add-Content -Path C:\Users\admtanjoh\Documents\JT.csv -Value $result
```

Comment: Pipe it to `Export-Csv -Append` instead of `Add-Content`

Comment: $result  | Export-Csv -Append -Force  -NoTypeInformation "C:\Users\admtanjoh\Documents\JT.csv"  is not giving me any errors but its actually not appending the results on to CSV